# Pop up a view in Xamarin Android using MVVM model

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, view, popupwindow

I know there are examples of popupviews and i can and did make a pop up window/alert dialog. But we are using MVVM model and using ShowViewModel method to show views. IT HAS TO BE LIKE THAT.

Now the actual situation.I have 2 screens.From screen 1 (listview) i select a list item. I come to screen 2.I have a button on screen 2(Submit button, not navigation buttons). Clicking that should show a pop up VIEW. Clicking OK should take me back to screen 1(listview). Simple. I have created a simple pop up.axml as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="50dp">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/DialogTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/AlertTextAppearance"
    local:MvxBind="Text Title"/>
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/DialogMessage"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     local:MvxBind="Text Message" />
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/OkBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    local:MvxBind="Click OKCommand"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

When i click on Submit I get a full activity window. I dont want that. I want a small exactly like pop up window, but with view. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Just starting to code Android using MVVM and Xamarin. I did use eclipse for Android dev in the past. So its different here.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend from  DialogFragment and then inflate your layout like this

public class YourDialog: DialogFragment
    {

```
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        // Get the layout inflater
        var inflater = Activity.LayoutInflater;

        _view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.your_layout, null);

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.SetView(_view);



        return builder.Create();
    }
```